# How to print in output window of visual studio express for windows phone?

Tags: c#, xcode, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-8

While debugging if I want to print a string in the output window, which method needs to be called?

In x-code we have `NSLog`. Do we have anything similar in visual studio?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("your string");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working perfectly!